# Mongoose - MongoDB | "Query was already executed" error on query in loop

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to collection queries in the while loop. But I'm getting a "Query was already executed" error. How can I do that? I have a custom field and I need to make sure it is unique. I also need to use this function elsewhere.

```js
async function createRandomID() {
  let id = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2, 6).toUpperCase();
  let unique = false;
  while (!unique) {
    await Deed.findOne({ deedId: id }, async (err, doc) => {
      if (!doc) {
        unique = true;
      }
      else {
        id = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2, 6).toUpperCase();
      }
    })
  }
  return id;
}

const addNewDeed = asyncErrorWrapper(async (req, res, next) => {
  let information = req.body;
  const deedId = await createRandomID();
  /*Other Operations...*/
});
```

Comment: Don't mix promises with callbacks. Also, why not use `ObjectId` as a unique id instead of a home-grown solution that takes up way more time to generate?

Comment: I also need a 4 digit unique ID. Humans will read this and it has to be easy. I can use objectID in queries but I also need a 4 digit key for humans.

Comment: I need to make sure the 4-digit unique key has not been used before.

Comment: There are only 10000 of such unique id's, so unless your system doesn't have many users you'll run out of unique id's quickly. But besides that, your issue is caused by mixing callbacks with promises (`await`).

Comment: I calculated that, there could be 1,679,616 different combinations. Because my random key is a mix of uppercase letters and numbers

Comment: can you elaborate on that a little bit? I'm a little confused

Comment: Four digits is from 0000 to 9999, so 10000 unique id's. I would have assumed you know the difference between promises and callbacks.